# Switch to **insert** mode from a user-defined command in Vim

Tags: vim

I'm defining my own command in my `vimrc`:

```
command! Tcs :normal lvf`hc
```

The aim is that I go on a backtick and it will delete the inner content from here to the next backtick. Like:

```
`hi there` -> ``
```

Problem is that is remains in normal mode, I would like to replicate the `c` command behaviour so that I can start typing immediately in **insert** mode.

I've tried `` command! Tcs :normal lvf`hc :startinsert `` but whatever I put after the last `c` will be typed directly in the editor.

Thanks

Comment: And  what's wrong with **ci`** (**c**hange **i**nside backtick)?!!! Which is a built in normal mode command and works even when you are not in between backticks.

Comment: oooh man. I never knew that one. Super nice. Was always `T\`ct\`` -ing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [**`:help :normal`**](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#:normal)
>

> ```
>         :norm[al][!] {commands}                   *:norm* *:normal*
>         (...)
>         {commands} should be a complete command.  If
>         {commands} does not finish a command, the last one
>         will be aborted as if <Esc> or <C-C> was typed.
> ```
>
> **`This implies that an insert command must be completed`**.
>
> ```
>        (...)
> ```

In your case the command `normal` has been aborted that's why you still in normal-mode. You can still try `:normal! i`

To get what you want instead you can do :

```
command! Tcs execute "normal lvf`hd" | :startinsert
```

Comment: it works, thank you! I actually read that help, but I couldn't understand the way you worked it out. I'd say it's a bit obscure.